# Windows virus scanners with scrutinized sources

Tags: windows, antivirus

I am growing concerned with the volume of likely state-sponsored malware and related attacks<sup>1</sup>.

I am worried that many nations have legislation allowing them to issue orders or otherwise compromise private endeavor<sup>2</sup> and often suppress discussion of these orders with gag orders.<sup>3</sup>

I am starting to consider the provenance and integrity of my virus scanner to be important.

**I would like a virus scanner that:**

1. Has an engine that is routinely scrutinized, and
2. Has virus definition data that is routinely scrutinized.

**I would consider these conditions met if:**

1. The above components are published Open Source, or
2. Are scrutinized by a trusted digital rights organization like [EFF](https://www.eff.org/) or [ORG](http://openrightsgroup.org/).

**Additional features required:**

1. Support for the Windows operating system.

**Desirable features:**

1. Choice of real-time, on-demand or scheduled scanning
2. Performance characteristics that compare with traditional commercial offerings
3. Detection characteristics that compare with traditional commercial offerings

*References:*

1: Attacks such as: [CIPAV](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2007/07/fbi-spyware-how/), [Flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_(malware)), [Stuxnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet), [Mask](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/02/meet-mask-posssibly-the-most-sophisticated-malware-campaign-ever-seen/) and recently [NSA Radio Hacks](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/15/us/nsa-effort-pries-open-computers-not-connected-to-internet.html?hp&_r=0).

2: Compromises such as: the [Clipper Chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_chip), [cryptography export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States#PC_era) restrictions, and recently [PRISM](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/politics/prism-collection-documents/).

3: Gags such as : [National security letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_security_letter#Contentious_aspects) e.g  [Twitter Subpoena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikiLeaks-related_Twitter_subpoenas#Subpoena_issued_with_accompanying_gag_order)

**Notes**:

- Related story about Avast [harvesting visited URLs](http://www.howtogeek.com/199829/avast-antivirus-was-spying-on-you-with-adware-until-this-week/) using a browser extension.
- Related story about NSA and GCHQ [targeting antivirus software network traffic](https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2015/06/22/nsa-gchq-targeted-kaspersky/) containing reports of hardware/software present on a system. ([slides‌​](https://www.eff.org/document/20150622-inercept-project-camberdada-nsa)).

Answer (score 3):

[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/) is Open Source, and I know that researchers and individuals scrutinize its source code.

I don't think any organization is tasked with auditing it on a regular basis, though.

[image]

Comment: That looks a lot fancier than I remember - is that clamwin?

Comment: While the ClamAV engine is open source, the windows "download" button on that website links to an installer for the closed source and very cloud-centric Immunet 3 product that also includes the SPERO and ETHOS engines ([source](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/about/win32/)).  In addition to uploading those files flagged as suspect, it will upload information about the files that exist on your machine, and which files you execute, to centralised servers ([source](http://www.immunet.com/privacy/index.html#virusdetection)).

Comment: @KellyThomas: I was not aware of this, thanks a lot for the information! I will try to update my answer, but don't hesitate to edit it as well!